# Why is the compiler compiling against the rules of precedence in below code?

Tags: c

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence, the assignment operators has the lowest precedence (before comma) among other operators.

However, when we execute the code below it prints `3`.

```
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=6,c=7;
    if (b%=(a%=b) * c >= 3 * c-b) 
        printf ("1");
    else if (a ? b : c == 0) 
        printf ("2");
    else if (c = c || a&&b) 
        printf ("3");
    else if (!c || printf ("4")) 
        printf("4");
}
```

What I say is that it should print `1` since `a%=b` would be compiled first (because it has brackets) and then compiler would do `a * c`, and finally it would compare with the expression `(3 * c-b)` , which is `3 * 7 - 6 = 15`. Since `a * c = 4 * 7 = 28` and `28>=15` is true , the output would be `1`.

Let's say , even if the first `if` is false , why would the second if be false? `a` is `4` and `b` is now `28` because of the first `if`, and the compiler will return the "true" part of ternary, which is `b` and because `b` is not `0`; the second `if` would be true.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209313/discussion-on-question-by-burr4ch-why-is-the-compiler-compiling-against-the-rule).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 28>=15 is true , the output would be 1.

Yes and after that `b %= 1` is 0, so the `if` is false.

It's:

```
b %= ((a%=b) * c >= 3 * c-b) =
... =
b %=             1           =
0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i realized i was contradicting myself!